# UserManager.Update not changing database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-identity

I've added to the .NET Identity structure and am trying to update a user's profile.  The database however isn't being updated even though it shows successful.  Can anyone see why the user's profile won't be updating?

Calling Method:

```
Dim _user As ApplicationUser = IdentityHelper.CurrentUser
Dim manager As UserManager = New UserManager()
_user.SelfEvaluationId = Nothing
manager.Update(_user)
```

ApplicationUser Class:

```
Public Class UserManager
    Inherits UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(New ApplicationDbContext()))
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class IdentityHelper

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property CurrentUser As ApplicationUser
        Get
            Dim manager As UserManager = New UserManager()
            Return manager.FindById(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId())
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: same problem my friend... How you fixed it ?